# Signal slots in Powermail

Tags: typo3, extbase

I am trying to extend Typo3 powermail 2.X version . My actually requirement is that , I will be creating a set of general field set under a storage folder. I mean , I will only creating  entries to 'tx_powermail_domain_model_pages' table and 'tx_powermail_domain_model_fields' .

What I want to achieve is that , I want to reuse the same field set in other forms as well.

```
`$signalSlotDispatcher = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3         \CMS\Extbase\SignalSlot\Dispatcher');

 $signalSlotDispatcher->connect(
 'In2code\Powermail\Controller\FormController',
 'formActionBeforeRenderView',
 'In2code\Powermailextended\Controller\FormController',
 'manipulateMailObjectOnCreate',
  FALSE
 );`
```

Tried to implement the same with signal shots . But couldn’t crack it down.

```
`<?php
 namespace In2code\Powermailextended\Controller;

/**
* Using a Slot to call a Powermail Signal
*
* Class FormControllerExtended
* @package In2code\Powermailextended\Controller
*/
class FormController {
public function manipulateMailObjectOnCreate($forms, $pObj) {
 }
}
```

Can anyone please advice me how I can implement this requirements ?

Answer (score 0):

using the setting in Extension Manager  we can implement this.
[image: This will server the purpose]